# Prevent click custom button when opportunity has specific picklist value

Tags: javascript, custom-button

On opportunity object I have a picklist with values: 'Y' and 'X'.
When opportunity has 'X' value user should be able to click button if has 'Y' when user click the button then should receive a information that value 'X' is needed to proceed.

Only value 'X' should allow click the button.

Does anybody know how in Salesforce achieve this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create Javascript button.

Below is the code snippet you can use in js button. I have considered account object as an example.

```
{!REQUIRESCRIPT('/soap/ajax/26.0/connection.js')} 
var accReq = "{!Account.Field__c}";
if(accReq != 'X') {
  alert('Only value X should allow click the button');
}
```

Comment: Thanks a looot!!!